# How to scale bitmap image from webservice?

Tags: android, imageview

Hi i have image url that is scalable i want to autofit into my imageview which i am using. Here is my image view code

```
<com.livetalkback.xfactor2012.ui.views.CmsRemoteImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_category_thumb_default" />
```

if append the url with required hieght & width then its adjust automatically But i dont want to append with hardcode height & width because my applications supports multiple screen size devices. Please help in this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find your imageView by id in your `onCreate(bundle savedInstanceState)` and set its source at `yourWebServiceQueryResult` in order to be able to decode it in sample size using the eponym method.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I assume your custom imageview is extending typical Android imageview. In this case you can use Scaletype as Fitxy property.

[more information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think are you fetching image and setting to given view , You can use  find  default width and height of your image and then find a aspect ratio of them and by what ratio you wish to scale u can resize it by mean of matrix

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// resize the bit map

   matrix.postScale(scaleWidth / width, scaleHeight / height);

// recreate the new Bitmap

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    bm.recycle();

    return resizedBitmap;
```